# Debugging a Maven Web Project in Eclipse(Understanding detailed flow)

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, debugging, jersey

I have debugged Java codes as JAVA APPLICATION.(its simple)
Now I am working with Maven project, and I am Keen to know comprehensive flow of this MAVEN+SPRING-JERSEY Project.

I guess debugging could help me with that, I have crawled many sites but cant really get how to debug a Maven Project.

Can anyone help me with this  babyish doubt.

Or even you can explain me flow from this example.[JERSEY+SPRING+MAVEN](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/)

Sorry ! I know This might be silly question,Let me know if I should delete it.

Please let me know if I am Correct: 
**WHAT I HAVE UNDERSTOOD:**

```
1.Request comes from client,Web.xml Handles this request.
It finds the REST class(with URIs) in given Package.

(Also in meantime,Spring registers all Beans with help of Bean Registry)

2.Then from Service It gets URI , Now request is sent to particular URI.

3.At that URI we have beans,(i.e business logic) which gets executed

4.Then this beans send back result to REST and REST send this response message to client.
```

This is My understanding from @Michael Hoffman answer.

Please Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: line by line execution,I want to know who talks with whom , how does code jumps to and fro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is simply providing you with build management. For most cases, it has no impact on how you will debug an application.

Based on your question, the best approach for debugging your application would be to use an IDE like Eclipse. You will need to have Tomcat, or a similar web container, in order to debug at runtime. Otherwise, the flow of code at design time is likely as follows:

1. At runtime, Spring loads any beans that are to be managed into the Spring container (application context). This may include the controller or service that is executed by the REST-ful call.
2. Web page or other integration makes a call to the rest service. The address depends on the configuration of the service across the web.xml and Spring application context.
3. A request flows through the configured servlet. Here is an example of servlet configuration in the web.xml of an app:

   ```
   <web-app>
       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
           <init-param>
               ...
           </init-param>
       </servlet>
       ...
       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       ...
   </web-app>
   ```
4. Based on the path requested, the request will flow to an implementing class, often times a controller or service class. The class or methods on the class will have annotation like: @Path("/helloWorld")

Comment: what role sspring play here? I understand REST is a Interface for request.

Comment: I've added a note for Spring. It manages beans. Think of it like a registry. Beans may include your controllers/services where the REST-ful call path flows through. From a debugging point of view, you may need to look into how beans have been loaded in the container at runtime, but likely not at compile time.